# Getting Plesk Panel to recognise a domain

Tags: domain

I have pointed a domain to my plesk panel, however now when I go to my domain it shows the "Web Server's Default Page"

My domain is hosted with company a, at company a's admin panel I have setup an A record to point

subdomain.mydomain.com to go to 11.11.11.11 which is an IP address associated with a domain on my plesk panel. e.g pleskdomain.com

How can I get subdomain.mydomain.com to show the content from pleskdomain.com ?

I assume there is a setting in plesk somewhere....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you get actually means web server doesn't know a site name.

You can either add "subdomain.domain.com" as an alias to "pleskdomain.com" or (if you are on Plesk 10.0+) add another site "domain.com" in Plesk and make subdomain "subdomain.domain.com" for it with docroot in the same folder as "pleskdomain.com" has. Both actions would make web server know there is a site "subdomain.domain.com" and its content located at the same place as "pleskdomain.com"

Comment: I am on Plesk 10 + but this sounds easier "...add "subdomain.domain.com" as an alias to "pleskdomain.com" how can I do this in Plesk 10?

Comment: In 10.4 (latest) just click "Add Alias" on toolbar, type "subdomain.domain.com" and be sure "Web" checkbox is enabled. For older versions you may need to look for "Domain Aliases" button.

As subdomain.domain.com is already resolving to your IP, it shall work just fine.

Comment: Genius! - Also for those of you reading this here is a useful video I found which backs up @Sergey L's answer : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hEJbfU98V4

Comment: As a follow up to this : Is there a way to accept ANY domains which might point at a domain? Something like domain alias = "*" ?